# Dar diferente formato numerico con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

¿Es posible realizar el number format que se hace en php pero en javascript ? Encontré que podría ser con `valor.toFixed();` pero no lo hace.
¿Alguien sabe otra manera de hacerlo? 
Algo como `46786.62` convertirlo a `46,786.62`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Puedes usar la función [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString), que convierte un número a cadena dándole el formato local especificado (y si no especificas ninguno, formateará el número al local que tenga el navegador por defecto).

El formato se lo puedes pasar como primer parámetro y debe ajustarse al [formato especificado aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Locale_identification_and_negotiation).

> NOTA - Un problema de esta función: Safari no la soporta en ninguna de sus versiones, y no funciona en versiones de IE anteriores a la 11.

Aquí dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var number = 46786.62;

// sin parámetros será el formato por defecto de tu navegador
console.log("Formato automático --- " + number.toLocaleString());

// le puedes pasar un código de locale específico
console.log("Formato en EE.UU. ---- " + number.toLocaleString("en-US"));
console.log("Formato de España ---- " + number.toLocaleString("es-ES"));
```

Comment: Ecelente me sirbio mucho tu respuesta!

Answer (score 1):

`.toFixed(2)` lo que hace como tal es agregar `00` después del numero entero o bien después de un punto.

Ahora lo que buscas hacer no hay método nativo en `javascript` que lo haga. tendrías que diseñar una función que lo haga, te dejo la función que buscas:

```js
var valor = 10000.34
console.log(addCommas(valor));
function addCommas(nStr)
{
 nStr += '';
 x = nStr.split('.');
 x1 = x[0];
 x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
 var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
 while (rgx.test(x1)) {
  x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
 }
 return x1 + x2;
}
```