# ¿Como hacer que mi input text tenga separador de miles y decimales en jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estoy intentando hacer un formato de moneda para mi input, lo cual quiero que se formatee automáticamente con separador de miles(",") y decimales; intente con varios plugins pero no me dan resultado.

```
function addCommas(nStr) {
        nStr += '';
        x = nStr.split('.');
        x1 = x[0];
        x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1)) {
                x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
        }
        return x1 + x2;
    }
```

Esto me agrega comas, pero solo para la primera unidad de miles :(

Este ejemplo de acá funciona, pero en un evento blur, como hago para ejecutarlo en un evento keyup.

```
$("#number").keyup(function() {

  this.value = parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, ""))
                    .toFixed(2)
                    .toString()
                    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
});
```

Comment: Muéstranos por favor lo que has intentado: plugins y ejemplo de código.

Comment: Revisa esta [respuesta en inglés](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18309744/4092887)

Comment: Esto me suena a otra pregunta parecida de SOes: http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/20400/250

Comment: si de ahí la saque, ya que queria explicar que es mas o menos lo que quiero hacer

Comment: Mauricio, el enlace que me pasaste sirve, pero como hago para realizarlo en un evento keyup.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona en el código que compartes?

Comment: Posible duplicado de: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74851/c%C3%B3mo-crear-input-din%C3%A1mico-que-convierta-n%C3%BAmeros-introducidos-a-sus-correspondie/74862#74862

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18657476/1595451

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Si tuvieses, por ejemplo:

```
<input id="number">
```

Entonces, con JQuery<sup>1</sup>:

```
$("#number").on({
    "focus": function (event) {
        $(event.target).select();
    },
    "keyup": function (event) {
        $(event.target).val(function (index, value ) {
            return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
                        .replace(/([0-9])([0-9]{2})$/, '$1.$2')
                        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ",");
        });
    }
});
```

<sup>* Véase en [***JSFiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/j0rxrun8/1/).</sup>

---

*Notas*

1. Adaptado de https://stackoverflow.com/a/18657757/870248

Comment: Hola Paul, gracias por el ejemplo, pero mi intención es hacerlo en el evento keyup, ya que necesito que cuando se vaya digitando el monto se vaya formateando automáticamente, y claro que el decimal no afecte el formato de miles.

Comment: Hola, @OscarE.Alvarado He actualizado el código para *formatear* la entrada en el evento `keyup`.

Comment: Excelente, gracias Paul.

Comment: como lo hago para que lo formatee sin decimales y solo separador de miles?

Comment: como lo hago para que lo formatee sin decimales y solo separador de miles? => la solución era comentar donde le reemplaza los dos decimales

Answer (score 11):

Hoy día, la mayoría de los navegadores modernos soportan [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) lo cual nos ayuda a dar formato a un número sin necesidad de recurrir a expresiones regulares ni a funciones específicas de jQuery.

Para mostrar coma como separador de miles, usarlo de la siguiente forma

```js
var numero = 1E6 + 56 / 100; //Un millón y 56 centésimas
document
  .getElementById('salida')
  .innerHTML = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-MX').format(numero);
```

```html
<div id="salida"></div>
```

```js
var numero = 1E6 + 56 / 100; //Un millón y 56 centésimas
$('#salida').html(new Intl.NumberFormat('es-MX').format(numero));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="salida"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Utiliza jQuery
jquery.maskedinput.min.js 
en la función mask, tu le das el formato que desees que tenga tu input

```
$('#txtMonto').mask('000,000,000.00', { reverse: true });
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo utilizo para ese caso [jquery.maskedinput.min.js](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) un plugin que te formatea la entrada del input

Un ejemplo sencillo es

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#date").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:"mm/dd/yyyy"});
   $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
   $("#tin").mask("99-9999999");
   $("#ssn").mask("999-99-9999");
});
```

Ademas de números, te permite formatear mas datos de entrada.

Comment: En el ejemplo veo fechas y teléfonos, ¿cómo sería para el caso particular que se pregunta?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro  tienes como quieres los numeros formateados?

Comment: Parece que OP quiere los números con `,` para separador de miles, millones, etc y `.` como separador de decimales.

Comment: Exacto, esto no seria de utilidad, ya que son mascaras.

Answer (score 0):

aquí te dejo una función en `javascript` que permite formatear un numero según una mascara dada, ademas la función permite procesar formular.

```js
// formatea un numero según una mascara dada ej: "-$###,###,##0.00"
//
// elm   = elemento html <input> donde colocar el resultado
// n     = numero a formatear
// mask  = mascara ej: "-$###,###,##0.00"
// force = formatea el numero aun si n es igual a 0
//
// La función devuelve el numero formateado

function MASK(form, n, mask, format) {
  if (format == "undefined") format = false;
  if (format || NUM(n)) {
    dec = 0, point = 0;
    x = mask.indexOf(".")+1;
    if (x) { dec = mask.length - x; }

    if (dec) {
      n = NUM(n, dec)+"";
      x = n.indexOf(".")+1;
      if (x) { point = n.length - x; } else { n += "."; }
    } else {
      n = NUM(n, 0)+"";
    } 
    for (var x = point; x < dec ; x++) {
      n += "0";
    }
    x = n.length, y = mask.length, XMASK = "";
    while ( x || y ) {
      if ( x ) {
        while ( y && "#0.".indexOf(mask.charAt(y-1)) == -1 ) {
          if ( n.charAt(x-1) != "-")
            XMASK = mask.charAt(y-1) + XMASK;
          y--;
        }
        XMASK = n.charAt(x-1) + XMASK, x--;
      } else if ( y && "$0".indexOf(mask.charAt(y-1))+1 ) {
        XMASK = mask.charAt(y-1) + XMASK;
      }
      if ( y ) { y-- }
    }
  } else {
     XMASK="";
  }
  if (form) { 
    form.value = XMASK;
    if (NUM(n)<0) {
      form.style.color="#FF0000";
    } else {
      form.style.color="#000000";
    }
  }
  return XMASK;
}

// Convierte una cadena alfanumérica a numérica (incluyendo formulas aritméticas)
//
// s   = cadena a ser convertida a numérica
// dec = numero de decimales a redondear
//
// La función devuelve el numero redondeado

function NUM(s, dec) {
  for (var s = s+"", num = "", x = 0 ; x < s.length ; x++) {
    c = s.charAt(x);
    if (".-+/*".indexOf(c)+1 || c != " " && !isNaN(c)) { num+=c; }
  }
  if (isNaN(num)) { num = eval(num); }
  if (num == "")  { num=0; } else { num = parseFloat(num); }
  if (dec != undefined) {
    r=.5; if (num<0) r=-r;
    e=Math.pow(10, (dec>0) ? dec : 0 );
    return parseInt(num*e+r) / e;
  } else {
    return num;
  }
}
```

```html
ingresar un valor numero (o formula) formatear con -$##,###,##0.00<br>
<input onchange="MASK(this,this.value,'-$##,###,##0.00',1)"><br>
<br>
ingresar un valor numero (o formula) formatear con 00/00/0000<br>
<input onchange="MASK(this,this.value,'00/00/0000',1)"><br>
```

Comment: exelente esta contribucion, pero hay 1 detalle cuando el usuario preciona "," como separador decimal el input lo toma como 1 entero !

Comment: Estimado @PiratadelProfit, aunque no hay una norma que establezca el punto "." o coma "," como separador decimal o de miles (y viceversa) nos encontramos que la distribución del teclado en español utiliza como separador decimal el punto en su bloque numérico, es por ello que la rutina la diseñe (y también por razones históricas) a que utilice el punto "." como separador decimal,  sin embargo la rutina es susceptible a modificaciones por lo que podrán adaptarla para que utilice la coma como separador decimal.