# ¿Cómo crear input dinámico que convierta números introducidos a sus correspondientes con decimales?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

Estoy trabajando con Laravel (y su motor de templates Blade). Tengo un *input* para colocar el precio de un producto:

```
<input type="text" 
    onkeydown="validateNumber(event)"  
    name="precio" 
    value="{{old('precio')}}" 
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Precio del articulo..."
    required>
```

Quiero que cuando se escriba por ejemplo 350000 sea convertido automaáticamente a 3.500.00

Comment: Hola, eso seria en javascript.

Comment: hola gracias por responder, conoces algun tutorial donde pueda guiarme

Comment: En este plugin te muestra https://github.com/customd/jquery-number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo mejor es que utilices algún plugin de jQuery, como:

- [jQuery Mask Plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/mask/)
- [jQuery InputMask](https://plugins.jquery.com/jquery.inputmask/)

Ya tienen contemplados muchos casos, ademas de que ofrecen mascaras según el tipo de dato o el formato que quieras utilizar. Si te encuentras limitado a implementarlo únicamente con javascript esta solución puede servirte:

```js
window.applyMask = function(input){
        console.log('applyMask');
        var unmasked = input.value.replace(/\./g,' ').replace(/ /g, '');
        input.value = addDots(unmasked);
     
  }

window.addDots = function(value){
    x = value.split(',');
    x1 = x[0]; // parte entera
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? ',' + x[1] : ''; // parte decimal
    // 3 digitos precedidos por una cantidad de 1 o mas digitos.
    // aplico regex para obtener 2 grupos cada 3 digitos
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    // $1 corresponde a los digitos predecesores, $2 al segundo grupo, los 3 dígitos que indican miles.
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
     //reemplaza la parte entera concatenando el primer grupo, un punto y el segundo grupo.
      x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + '.' + '$2');
    }
    // concatena con parte decimal
    return x1 + x2;
}

inputId = document.getElementById('valueInput');
window.onload = applyMask(inputId)
```

```html
<input id="valueInput" placeholder= "Insert value here"  onkeyup="applyMask(this);" />
```

Comment: Sería importante que también funcione al momento de cargar la página, pues lo que hace Laravel es en caso de un error de validación, volver al formulario y mostrar los datos previamente ingresados.

Comment: Te refieres a que no este ligada únicamente al onkeyup y que ejecute para todos los inputs que sean "importe" en el onLoad?

Comment: Exactamente, así funcionaría perfecto para lo que lo quiere el OP y tendrías mi +1.

Comment: Edité el fiddle, espero tu comentario :)

Comment: Al parecer funciona, tal vez sería bueno que agregues el resto del código acá también. +1

Comment: Edite la respuesta con el código actualizado. Espero que al OP le sirva :) ! .

Comment: gracias amigo me funciono perfecto