# se puede agregar caracteres por default a un input text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Existe alguna forma de que cuando ingrese un valor al input se agrege un caracter como un punto o coma,es muy parecido a lo que hace el input date que te viene con los "/" y que cuando tu ingresar se acomoda con los "/", esto se puede aplicar en un input text?

Comment: Te refieres a una mascara? echale un vistazo a esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74851/c%C3%B3mo-crear-input-din%C3%A1mico-que-convierta-n%C3%BAmeros-introducidos-a-sus-correspondie/74862#74862

Comment: En teoría, con JS se puede hacer un evento que al cumplirse agregue, reemplaze, añada, o superponga uno o más caracteres.

Comment: Popisw lo has logrado? Si he respondido tu pregunta no olvides marcarla como respuesta. Si has tenido algun otro problema, puedes exponer tu situacion para ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta a tu pregunta es: Si, si puedes agregar caracteres por default a un input text.

En los comentarios puedes ver un ejemplo de como agregar caracteres en diferentes partes del input para dar un formato específico a la entrada de texto.

Si solo deseas agregar caracteres, tal y como lo indica tu pregunta, bastará con hacer algo como lo siguiente:

Algunos ejemplos usando JQuery que es lo mas común:

Agregar al final:

```
$("#id-input").on("input",function(){
    var v = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(v+"x");//Puedes reemplazar "x" con cualquier otro caracter.
});
```

Agregar un punto para tener "dos decimales":

```
$("#id-input").on("input",function(){
    var v = $(this).val();
    if(v.toString().length > 2)
    {
        if(v.indexOf(".") > 0)
            v = v.slice(0,v.indexOf("."))+v.slice(v.indexOf(".")+1); 
        $(this).val(v.slice(0,-2)+"."+v.slice(-2));
    }

});
```

Según sea el formato que necesites, puede agregar los caracteres que necesites.

Comment: ya lo intente pero no funciona `$("#intalla").on("input",function(){
    var v = $(this).val();
    if(v.length > 2)
        $(this).val(v.slice(0,-2)+"."+v.slice(-2));//Reemplaza el punto por cualquier otro caracter. Reemplaza los indices de las funciones slice para cualquier otro lugar en el input.
}); `<input type="number"   id = "intalla" name="talla"  required placeholder="TALLA"  autocomplete="off"   style="height: 20%; width: 128%;">`

Comment: Si quieres agregar algun caracter en especifico, puedes editar la pregunta, poner el codigo con el que lo estas intentando y podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta. Me faltaba un `.toString()` en el if que evalua la variable `v`. Lo siento mucho. Con eso te deberia funcionar perfectamente. Si te ha ayudado mi respuesta, recuerda marcala como aprobada.

Comment: Tambien he añadido una verificacion del punto, para que funcione con cualquier cantidad de numeros. Espero que te funcione! Saludos!

Comment: @ingswsm si te ha servido la respuesta, para obtener mas reputacion y ayudar al sitio, puedes marcarla como aceptada.