# Agregar numeros negativos a Expresion Regular validando millares

Tags: javascript, regex, autonumeric

pude obtener este codigo desde otra publicacion mas antigua [¿Como hacer que mi input text tenga separador de miles y decimales en jquery?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23179/como-hacer-que-mi-input-text-tenga-separador-de-miles-y-decimales-en-jquery), eh intentado de varias formas editar la expresion regular pero no encuentro la manera de sacarle los decimales y a su vez que permita numeros negativos, agradecia cualquier ayuda. Use este codigo porque es el unico que encontre que edita el valor del input mientras lo estoy cargando, si hay otro tipo de solucion no tengo problema en cambiarla :D

```
   <input type="text" id="miles">

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#miles").on({
    "focus": function (event) {
        $(event.target).select();
    },
    "keyup": function (event) {
        $(event.target).val(function (index, value ) {
            return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
                     //   .replace(/([0-9])([0-9]{0})$/, '$1,$2')
                        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ".");
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: para que tu pregunta sea mejor recivida agrega un ejemplo de entrada de los inputs y el resultado esperado!

Comment: lo que hace es cambiar el valor ingresado en el input mientras lo cargas por ejemplo si podes 200 no hace nada pero donde pusiste 2000 lo transforma automáticamente a 2.000 eso funciona bien, pero me gustaria tambien poder poder -2000 y que lo transforme a -2.000

Answer (score 0):

En tu código, con esto estás eliminando al signo negativo, ya que reemplaza todo caracter que no es un dígito por `""`.

```
replace(/\D/g, "")
```

Para que elimine todo lo que no sea un dígito **ni un signo negativo**:

```
replace( /[^-\d]+/g, "")
```

Luego de eso, probablemente deberías validar que esté al inicio, o que no tenga 2 signos.