# Separador de miles en un input RANGE y TEXT

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

estoy intentando hace que un range muestre una cantidad en euros con separador decimal y con un campo para escribir el numero lo mismo. En el campo escrito lo he conseguido pero con la barra del range no muestra el punto.

```js
$("#ningresos").on({
         "focus": function(event) {
        $(event.target).select();
        },
        "keyup": function(event) {
    $(event.target).val(function(index, value) {
      return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ".");
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="range" id="ingresos" name="amountRange" min="0" max="35000" value="0" step="500" oninput="this.form.amountInput.value=this.value" />
        <input type="number" class="precio" id="ningresos"name="amountInput" min="0" max="35000"  value="0" oninput="this.form.amountRange.value=this.value" />

    </form>
```

Comment: [¿Responde este otro enlace tu pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23179/como-hacer-que-mi-input-text-tenga-separador-de-miles-y-decimales-en-jquery)

Comment: El problema es que es de typo range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que te parece si usamos el evento `change` pero del range para ejecutar el cambio, creo que puede funcionar de esta manera ya que desde aqui se encadena la reacción, en el otro sentido creo que seria prudente usar un `trigger`.

```js
$("#ingresos").on({
         "change": function(event) {
          var value_in = $("#ningresos").val();
          value_in = value_in.replace(/\D/g, "")
            .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ".");
          $("#ningresos").val(value_in);
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="range" id="ingresos" name="amountRange" min="0" max="35000" value="0" step="500" oninput="this.form.amountInput.value=this.value" />
        <input type="number" class="precio" id="ningresos"name="amountInput" min="0" max="35000"  value="0" oninput="this.form.amountRange.value=this.value" />

    </form>
```

En el caso de que desees usar tu codigo agregarle el `trigger` debes, ya que este accionara el evento de tu otro input.

```js
$("#ingresos").on({
  "change": function(event) {
      $("#ningresos").trigger("keyup");
    }
});

$("#ningresos").on({
         "focus": function(event) {
        $(event.target).select();
        },
        "keyup": function(event) {
    $(event.target).val(function(index, value) {
      return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ".");
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="range" id="ingresos" name="amountRange" min="0" max="35000" value="0" step="500" oninput="this.form.amountInput.value=this.value" />
        <input type="number" class="precio" id="ningresos"name="amountInput" min="0" max="35000"  value="0" oninput="this.form.amountRange.value=this.value" />

    </form>
```