# Mostrar valor en forma de numero o moneda

Tags: php, javascript, html

un formulario que recibe 3 inputs, donde solo realizan una operacion entre 2 inputs y la muestra en el tercer input. Mi pregunta es como puedo mostrar el resultado en formato de moneda o numero separado por miles.

**EJEMPLO** input 1 recibe 15432, input 2 recibe 45000 y input 3 recibe el resultado de la operacion que es 7251.84 **pero** necesito que muestre el resultado separado por miles osea **7,251.84**

```
            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-xs-4">

                <div class="input-group">
              
                    <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg " name="nuevoValorI" id="nuevoValorI"  placeholder="Valor Viaje de Ida"  required>

                  </div>

              </div>
             
              <div class="col-xs-4">

                <div class="input-group">
            
                  <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg " name="nuevoValorR" id="nuevoValorR"  placeholder="Valor Viaje de Regreso"  required>

                </div>

              </div>
              
              <div class="col-xs-4">

                <div class="input-group">
            
                  <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg " name="Total" id="Total"  placeholder="Valor Viaje Nosotros-Regreso"  required>

                </div>

              </div>
              

            </div>
```

en JS TENGO

```
var ViajeI = Number($("#nuevoValorI").val());
   var ViajeR = Number($("#nuevoValorR").val());

   var PorcentajeEllos = ((ViajeI+ViajeR)*0.12);
   
     $('#Total').val(PorcentajeEllos);     /*Aqui es donde muestra el resultado*/
```

Comment: Creo que esto resuelve tu pregunta [separar por miles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23179/como-hacer-que-mi-input-text-tenga-separador-de-miles-y-decimales-en-jquery)

Comment: Puedes apoyarte con [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat). Entre otros tipos de formato, te permite hacerlo para moneda.